# Why does the C# compiler generate CS0436 warnings for internal classes?

Tags: c#, warnings, compiler-warnings

I'm using the JetBrains annotations in a C# solution. I've brought the annotations classes into each project of the solution as a linked file. I didn't want the JetBrains annotations to be part of my public interface, so I modified them to be internal rather than public.

However, when I compile I get lots of warnings CS0436, for example:

> C:\src\foo\bar.cs(12,29): warning CS0436: The type 'JetBrains.Annotations.NotNullAttribute' in 'C:\src\Common\JetBrains\JetBrains.cs' conflicts with the imported type 'JetBrains.Annotations.NotNullAttribute' in 'c:\src\blah\bin\Debug\blah.dll'. Using the type defined in 'C:\src\Common\JetBrains\JetBrains.cs'.

But in JetBrains.cs, NotNullAttribute is internal:

```
internal sealed class NotNullAttribute : Attribute { }
```

I don't understand why the compiler is warning about importing types that are internal to another assembly. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure it's internal in `blah.dll` as well? And the internals of that assembly haven't been made visible to this one?

Comment: Yes, a single, common JetBrains.cs file was linked into both projects. All of the types in my JetBrains.cs file are internal.

Comment: Do you have something protected or private in the sealed class?

If yes the warning is shown because it does not make any sense to define protected/private in a class which can't be inherited from.

Comment: No, the entire class definition is listed here. (Also, the warning you are referring to is warning CS0628.)

Comment: @Hugh: But have you rebuilt `blah.dll` before rebuilding the other project? Can you show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem?

Comment: I've just tried to reproduce it myself, and failed - it works fine.

Comment: Yes, I rebuilt the whole thing. I went so far as to delete my entire working directory and pull from source afresh. I'll see if I can isolate an example.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ys1ykk(v=vs.80).aspx, thats why the warning is displayed. The real question is, why is there a conflict?

Comment: Is there any internalsvisibleto attributes set between blah.dll and your new project ?

Comment: **Just what is `blah.dll`** from the error message? Maybe you are referencing a compiled version of some JetBrains project where the `JetBrains.Annotations.NotNullAttribute` is defined as a public class, while at the same time you copy the source code (and modify the accessibility to `internal`).

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: it's another DLL that's being built in the same solution. It gets its JetBrains.Annotations classes from the same file as all the others in the solution; there are no JetBrains-related classes with public visibility in the entire solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the problem. The "blah.dll" assembly I mentioned had this in its AssemblyInfo.cs:

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("my.other.assembly")]
```

Thanks for the input everyone.

Comment: Ah, it was suggested in the very first comment your question received.

Comment: Yep. Unfortunately I didn't know such an attribute existed so I didn't know that's what he meant.

Comment: There's more info on this, [Friend Assemblies (C# and Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0tke9fxk.aspx).

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem because in the References folder there was a reference to the same project. ie: my project name was Store and the reference had the same name. I removed it and problem solved! good luck